# undefined method `each' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I've got a HAML file which works:

```
%h2 
  #{@schedule_item.schedule_id}
```

and prints the ID.

I then try:

`%h2
    - @schedule_item.each do |test|
      %li test`

and get the error: undefined method `each' ScheduleItem:0x007ff8b91c06b0

can someone explain why I can't run each on this instance variable?

Comment: You cannot run `each` on a single instance, it has to be an array or enumareble of some kind.

Comment: is that `@schedule_item` a single instance or a collection ? you can't run `each` on a single instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`each` is a method that can be used on collection objects/Arrays

Although, i cannot see the reason you are iterating a single instance, however if you want to run `each` on single instance, you need to first cast it as an array like this.

```
%h2
  - Array(@schedule_item).each do |test|
    %li test
```

Comment: great, thanks. Is there an easy way to inspect/debug instance variables when I'm stuck like this? If I want to view all info about the variable, do I just print it to the dom?

Comment: you could just do something like `= @item.inspect` on your haml file to inspect the object you're receiving on your template.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem too. My problem was, I had forgotten `def index` in the controller. After I defined it, the problem was solved. 

`class GroupsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @groups = Group.all
  end
end`